# Python POST requests on Facebook "forgot password" not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, http-post, python-requests

I wanna make script, which recover my account, so i wanna send my email to input by POST and scrap next page. My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Soup = BeautifulSoup


#Parse page, i need "lsd_value" to send POST request
x = requests.get('http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover')
x.encoding = "utf-8"
parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")
print(parsed)

lsd_value = parsed.find('input', {'name': 'lsd'})
output_lsd_value = lsd_value['value']
print(lsd_value['value'])

#POST 
headers = {
"Host": "m.facebook.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
"Accept-Encoding":  "gzip, deflate, br"}
payload={
"lsd": output_lsd_value,
"email": "correct facebook_email",
"did_submit": "Search"
}

#Send and print POST request
session = requests.Session()
x = session.post('http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover', 
headers=headers, data=payload)
print "x.content:", x.content
x.encoding = "utf-8"
parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")
print"parsed:", parsed
```

Script not find my profile i think POST requests i not valid, but i dont know why.

Update 1:
Headers updated, but now i have many diamonds with question marks... Problem with coding? My output:

```
parsed: � �oM��=cv�!���WZ�?CS���1��k����|
���:Uaz��LN��)!M�+��U���Ț�V雳��4!
```

Comment: You have skipped the header part. Facebook is sending so many headers with that url and you are sending the only one

Comment: @Ujjaval Moradiya
Headers updated, but now i have many diamonds with question marks... Problem with coding?

Comment: Maybe facebook is using some kind of character set or encryption mechanisms. Don't know what is this but yes your url worked with the headers.